# rel=canonical required for HTTPS?

Tags: https, canonical-url

I'm offering a page through HTTP and HTTPS, both with the same URL scheme. I.e., a page is available as `http://www.example.com/page1.html` as well as `https://www.example.com/page1.html`.

Should I add `rel=canonical` to one of those pages?

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is a bit shorter than this one the [accepted answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/3147/1643) points to [this article](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) which says:

> Yes, you can use rel="canonical" for https to http or vice versa.
>   Rel="canonical" is already live in Google's indexing process and has
>   shown results for our trusted testers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really necessary, but it never hurts to use a canonical URL anyway.